# Should a function use: return null;?

Tags: php

Should a function return `null`?

E.g.

```
function test()
{
    return null; // vs return;
}
```

Is the latter considered bad practice or doesn't it matter?

PS

Whether it is bad practice shouldn't be subjective IMHO.

Comment: If you have a practice of indicating that `null` value means something specific, i.e. function arguments contain bad data - then go ahead. But often boolean return is more than enough, though. I use `null` in anonymous funcs that are expected to return actual data, so boolean `false` is considered an acceptable return, but `null` is not.

Comment: We can conclude that it is redundant, as the runtime already does that. But that doesn't make it bad or unuseful. The answer is explicitness. More interestingly, shouldn't you write `NULL`?

Comment: @mario you mean `null` vs `NULL`?

Comment: @PeeHaa: Yes, I believe the uppercase variant is the canonical token. And going back to explicitness, it has a bigger announcement effect.

Comment: Isn't not writing return even more explicit here?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you don't return anything, just use `return;` or omit it at all at the end of the function.
If your function is usually returns something but doesn't for some reason, `return null;` is the way to go.

That's similar to how you do it e.g. in C: If your function doesn't return things, it's `void`, otherwise it often return either a valid pointer or NULL.

Comment: True, but this way it's more clear that the return value will probably be used by the caller.

Comment: Unless there isn't any documentation, I find it hard to say. What do you read first? The last line of the function body or the return type docs just in it's head?

Comment: Not every project uses doc comments.

Comment: Not every function returns something. Or should the code here clearly document that NULL is to be returned for those who don't speak the language? Okay, I see the answer changed, so I think it's clear.

Answer (score 66):

Always is a good practice to show what you're returning.

But as a tip, the following are all equivalent:

```
function test()
{
    return null;
}


function test()
{
    return;
}


function test()
{

}
```

In all cases there for `var_dump(test());` will be:

```
NULL
```

Comment: The last function example is very clear about the point that there is nothing to return. So which example shows best in your eye?

Comment: As in first comment... Always is a good practice to show what you're returning. So my choice is first one.

Comment: So first you show that you return something to then finish the sentence to say that that something is `NULL` instead making less words and therefore stating the obvious?

Comment: I would go with the following approach for semantic meaningful programming: http://www.dereuromark.de/2015/10/05/return-null-vs-return-void

Comment: $foo = NULL; print $foo; will NOT throw an error but print $foo; will.

Answer (score 13):

When you use **[return type declarations](http://php.net/manual/functions.returning-values.php)** with the nullable prefix "?" there is a difference!

The PHP documentation says ...

> As of PHP 7.1.0, return values can be marked as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark (?). This signifies that the function returns either the specified type or NULL.

So, when you return nothing the error message will be:

`Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of test() must be of the type string or null, none returned in ...`

And when you return `return;` the error message will be:

`Fatal error: A function with return type must return a value (did you mean "return null;" instead of "return;"?) in ...`

When you return `null`, everything is fine.

See https://3v4l.org/5NTvg

Comment: Presumably this is because, since PHP 7.1, `void` is a special return type (for functions which do not return a value), and now distinct from `null` (which is the value `null`) when it comes to comes to function return values/types.  Though if you tried to assign the return value to a variable in either case your variable would end up with the value `null`.  (See also the [PHP RFC for `void` return type](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type).)

Answer (score 11):

An undefined function return value in PHP always equals `NULL`, so it does not make any difference (the runtime does this).

What makes a difference is that you make use of docblocks and document the return value with the `@return` tag so clever IDE's offer info here.

If you want to signal per the docblock that not-returning a value is intended, you can use `void`:

```
 * @return void
```

If you want to signal that returning `NULL` is intended, you can use `null` or `NULL` (depending on your code-style for uppercase PHP standard constants):

```
 * @return null
```

or:

```
 * @return NULL
```

That should make the coders intention visible as by PHP this is would be always `null` as the factual return value.

**Read on:**

More details and updated information is [in PeeHaa's answer to this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39638662/367456).

Answer (score 10):

It is just plain silly to return `null` if there is nothing to return. Doing `return;` shows intend of not actually returning anything. And makes it clear what the function does.

The fact that PHP does not have a `void` return type yet should not be a reason to make the intend less clear. Also note that PHP 7.1 will provide support for [the `void` return type](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type):

```
function test(): void {
    return null; // this will error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, I don't think there's a difference between the two. According to the [PHP documentation on return](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

> If no parameter is supplied, then the parentheses must be omitted and
> NULL will be returned.

I personally like putting the NULL there. Then there's no question as to what's being returned, making your debugging a little easier.

Comment: That's true. I just like being verbose, I guess. When I'm looking at my code 1 year from now, late at night, trying to figure out what's broken, I like having everything in front of me (nothing is implied). Personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

The PEAR best practices page does a `return null` in their "Return early" example. This increases readability which we should always try to do since we write code for humans, not computers.

source: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.bestpractices.php