# No need to return for null value?

Tags: php, function, null, return, return-type

I just wanna understand the logic behind this. Without returning the `null` how the function is returning the `NULL`. I initially thought it should return `void`. Any explanations for this

```
var_dump (test(true)); // Result 500
var_dump (test(false)); // Result NULL

public function test($value)
    {
        if ($value) {
            return '500';
        } else {
            null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the manual:

> If the return is omitted the value **NULL** will be returned.

`null` in PHP means no value. If your function returns no value it means that you will get `null`, which is a special constant.

The following will all return `null`:

```
function a():void {
    null; // no return
}

function a() {
    return ; // return without value
}

function a() {
    // empty function
}
```

PHP 7.1 introduced new type called `void`. If you declare a function as void it means it can't return anything, not even `null`, but if you try to use the returned value from a void function you will always get `null`. The reasoning behind this is explained in [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php).

Answer (score -1):

This is normal behaviour in PHP. From the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php):

> If the return is omitted the value **`NULL`** will be returned.

The Stack Overflow question [Should a function use: return null;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749091/should-a-function-use-return-null) may also be helpful for you, the following quote is from the accepted answer there:

> If your function doesn't return things, it's void, otherwise it often return either a valid pointer or NULL.

(This depends on whether your statement evaluates to `true` or `false`.)

So your function returns `500` if the condition returns `true`, and `null` when it is not, because no `return` statement is reached and executed.